# What is the difference between anti-symmetric wavefunction and asymmetric wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, identical-particles

In section 8.2.4, Zettili, in his book Quantum Mechanics, explains how we can construct symmetric and anti-symmetric wavefunctions using asymmetric wavefunction. Although he explains that symmetric and anti-symmetric wavefunctions give positive and negative signs respectively under the interchange of any pair of particles, he seems to have missed explaining asymmetric wave function and its properties.

What is the asymmetric wavefunction, and what are its properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [asymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetry) wave function has no symmetry under exchange of particles. In other words, there is no relation between $\Psi(x_1, x_2)$ and $\Psi(x_2, x_1)$ that holds for all values of $x_1, x_2$.

Comment: I think OP is referring to (anti-) symmetry with respect to exchange of particles, not with respect to reflection i.e. $\Psi(x_1,x_2)=\pm\Psi(x_2,x_1)$ instead of $\Psi(x)=\pm\Psi(-x)$. OP mentions exchange of particles and the section mentioned refers to particle exchange as well.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Ah yes, my bad. Fixed.